# RelativeLayout with two textviews on one horizontal line with ellipsis support

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I am trying to setup a RelativeLayout where two TextView are shown on one line.  The first TextView should be aligned to the left.  The second TextView should be aligned to the right.  If the second TextView text would expand to overlap the first TextView then I want to ellipsize the text in the middle.  I don't want to ellipsize the first TextView.

This is what I have come up with. The problem is the second TextView is directly to the right of the first TextView instead of being aligned to the far right.  It seems like I cannot use alignParentRight and toRightOf at the same time.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="[DetailedType]"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Left"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="[CustomerName]"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic idea to achieve this id to add a dummy invisible view in the horizontal center of your `RelativeLayout` and the tell the left `TextView` to be to the left of it and the right `TextView` to be to the right of it... see below

About your problem with aligning it to the right, you should stretch the TextView to take half of the screen and then set `android:gravity="right"` on the TextView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/dummy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Left"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/dummy"
        android:text="[DetailedType]"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Right"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Left"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="[CustomerName]"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But you can always use `LinerLayout` to the job

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Left"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="[DetailedType]"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Right"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="[CustomerName]"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is there any way to make the right TextView expand all the way to the end of the left TextView?  As it stands the right TextView is ellipsizing text when it goes past the horizontal center of the control.  I only wanted the text to ellipsize if the right text would overlap the left text.  Right now it's ellipsizing text if the right text overlaps the horizontal center of the view.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you only miss `android:gravity="right"` on your right view.